# Looping two arrays to make html table in php

Tags: php

I have two array, one is meant for table heading and second is meant for table data.

**Table Heading array**

```
  Array
  (
   [0] => techrepublic.com
   [1] => office.microsoft.com
   [2] => en.pstrecovery.net
   [3] => easeus.com
   [4] => download.cnet.com
   [5] => datanumen.com
   [6] => 2324
 )
```

**Table Data array**

```
  Array
(
   [software services] => Array
    (
        [datanumen.com] => 2
        [office.microsoft.com] => 3
        [easeus.com] => 8
        [download.cnet.com] => 9
        [en.pstrecovery.net] => 10
    )

[software services in Delhi] => Array
    (
        [en.pstrecovery.net] => 1
        [datanumen.com] => 3
        [office.microsoft.com] => 4
        [easeus.com] => 9
        [download.cnet.com] => 10
    )

[orignal software services] => Array
    (
        [en.pstrecovery.net] => 1
        [easeus.com] => 6
        [download.cnet.com] => 7
        [datanumen.com] => 8
        [office.microsoft.com] => 9
    )
```

)

I want output table as shown in attachment [image]

What i have done till now

```
    // code for table heading
    foreach ( $_POST['competitor']) as $value) { // $_POST['competitor']) 
                                                // containts table heading 
                                                // array
          echo "<th>". $value ."</th>"  ;
    }

  //code for table row 

     foreach ($details as $Keywords => $comp) {  // $details contains row
                                    // data array
       echo '<tr><td>' .$Keywords .  '</td>';
       foreach ($_POST['competitor'] as $competitor) {
        if (isset($comp[$competitor])) {
             echo '<td>' . $comp[$competitor] . '</td>' ;
        } else {
        echo '<td>Not Found</td>' ;
       }
      }
       echo '</tr>' ;
      }
```

I am unable to arrange td and tr. How can I achieve the output as shown in attachment?

Currently  i am getting following output which is wrong  :[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to arrange td and tr"? What does your output HTML look like presently?

Comment: my means how to arrange / or make loop to arrange table rows and column as shown in attachment

Comment: That doesn't fully answer my question. What are you getting presently? I think this question is rather leaning towards "too broad" or "no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" at present.

Comment: Dear i have attached a output format , i have to write to write code in such a  manner so that i can get desired output

Comment: Yes, I understand. Asking for a third time: what are you getting at the moment?

Comment: see edited part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, in order to get the data in the same order as the headers, you need to loop through the headers again for each row in the data. Since your data uses the headers as array keys, this should be pretty easy.

```
foreach ( $_POST['competitor'] as $value) {
    echo "<th>". htmlspecialchars($value) ."</th>"  ;
}

foreach ($details as $Keywords => $comp) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($Keywords) .  '</td>';


    // iterate the headers here instead
    foreach ($_POST['competitor'] as $competitor) {

        // echo the value for that header from the current row if it's present
        if (isset($comp[$competitor])) {
            echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($comp[$competitor]) . '</td>' ;
        } else {
            echo '<td>Not Found</td>' ;
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>' ;
}
```

Side note - don't forget to escape your strings properly for HTML output.

Comment: You might want to make a note about HTML escaping as well, even if you don't actually add it to your example. Characters like `&` will cause the HTML to be invalid, and an unclosed `<` will stop the page from rendering at all.

Comment: @halfer good point. I was more focused on the logic problem, but that part is certainly important.

Comment: @wasimbeg I have. I'm trying to figure out how it could have produced that output.

Comment: @wasimbeg ah, so you got it figured out? I was at a loss, honestly.

Comment: No , i am waiting for your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152469/discussion-between-wasim-beg-and-dont-panic).

Comment: Thanks alot, you save my day, your solution is absolutely right, By mistake, i sort the order of heading

Comment: @wasimbeg Great, I'm glad you got it figured out.